# Sonatype Nexus 3 Force Local Index

Tags: repository, nexus, sonatype

I'm setting up Nexus 3 for my company and I want to get a local copy of the maven/apache repositories. In Nexus 2.x.x they had a repo option of “Download Remote Indexes” being set to true to do this. I can't seem to find this in 3.x.x. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature for usage of the remote index is not yet implemented in Nexus Repository Manager 3.x. It will probably be part of 3.2 or a later release.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @manfred-moser - is this implemented now? we just installed nxrm 3 and I dont see any options for indexing artifacts from remote repo. I tried searching online in help documentation and could not find anything either.

Comment: I am not involved with Sonatype Nexus anymore but I do not think it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Nexus Repository Manager 3.2 does NOT support usage of remote index for searches (and other purposes) at all.
This was not yet implemented even in Nexus Repository Manager version 3.20.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41470500

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-13392

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-22698