# How to download remote index in Nexus OSS 3.2?

Tags: maven, nexus

I successfully installed Nexus OSS 3.2, but I get no search results, for example for "junit". Also under Browse / Components / Maven Central are no components listed.

I found [NEXUS-9563](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9563) with following answer:

> This means that the search indexes from Central haven't been downloaded. Have you set "Download Remote Indexes" to "true" in the central proxy repository's configuration?

But I can't find an option "Download Remote Indexes" in Nexus OSS 3.2. See proxy settings for Maven Central:

[image: Proxy settings]

I tried:

- Button [Rebuild index](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.2/reference/admin.html#admin-repository-repositories):

  > The Rebuild Index button allows you to drop and recreate the search index for the proxy repository, synchronizing the contents with search index. This button is only available for proxy repositories.
- Task of type [Publish Maven indexes](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.2/reference/admin.html#admin-system-tasks):

  > Maven indexes can be used to download an index of available components to a client including a developer’s IDE, for example. The task publishes the index for all or a specific Maven repository.

but nothing downloaded the remote index.

How can I download the remote index of a proxy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nexus Repository Manager 3.2 does NOT support usage of remote index for searches (and other purposes) at all. If you want this feature I suggest to stick with Nexus Repository Manager 2 for now.

Comment: Is this anywhere documentated? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Well.. its not there as a feature.. so its not there in the documentation. There is no official document about all the missing features in 3 from all I know.

Comment: Unfortunately Nexus 2 doesn't support npm (enough), see [NEXUS-6857](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6857).

Comment: Fair enough... not sure if v2 will get scope support any time soon.

Comment: the problem is query of components returns nothing, even common lib such as lucene, then how to search in nexus3?

Comment: Dont search in Nexus.. instead you need to search in the search interface of the remote repositories. Painful but necessary.

Comment: Wait, there is a **Rebuild Index** button which does nothing? Note that the NetBeans IDE will be unable to offer numerous Maven-related features if connected to a repository manager which does not support indices. So I guess this is a good reason to stay on Nexus 2.

Comment: @ManfredMoser: *Dont search in Nexus.. instead you need to search in the search interface of the remote repositories. Painful but necessary.* Did it change after 2,5 years? Do you know? [NEXUS-13392](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-13392) is also still open.